# How can I get the total memory (RAM) of a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Is there any `kubectl` command to see how much RAM (e.g. GB) has the entire cluster?

Basically I would like to get the sum of all the RAM of all the nodes in the cluster.

The command would be useful to understand the "size" of the Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: `kubectl get node -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]} {.metadata.name} {.status.allocatable}{"\n"}{end}'` this would give allocatable resources in your cluster.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/#node-allocatable

Comment: you can also use the kubectl plugin called `view-utilization` for having a nice table view.

Answer (score 4):

You can install `view-utilization` kubectl plugin with:

```
kubectl krew install view-utilization
```

Then you can run:

```
kubectl view-utilization -h
```

...and you should look for values under "Alloc" columns:

```
Resource   Req  %R   Lim  %L  Alloc  Sched  Free
CPU        3.7  6%   4.3  7%     60     57    56
Memory    5.4G  2%  7.9G  3%   237G   232G  229G
```